# Repeatedly Iterating Through a List

Tags: c#, list, queue, iteration, repeat

I have a list like such:

```
List<Thing> foo = new List<Thing>();
foo.PopulateWithFourThings();
```

And I want to iterate through it over and over, such as 0123012301230123...

Foreach is not what I am looking for, because I do not want everything all at once.  I have been messing with Queues, and am wondering if Queues are appropriate here?  Or if there is something better than Queues for this.

I am looking for the best code practice in this situation (repeatedly iterate through a list).

So is there a better option than:

```
    if (nextElementIsNeeded)
    {
        Thing thing = foo[0];
        foo.RemoveAt(0);
        foo.Add(thing);
        return thing;
    }
```

Or the following code using a Queue:

```
    Queue<Thing> foo = new Queue<Thing>();
    foo.PopulateWithForThings();
    //////////////////////////////////////
    if (nextElementIsNeeded)
    {
        Thing thing = foo.Dequeue();
        foo.Enqueue(thing);
        return thing;
    }
```

Comment: `RemoveAt(0)` is very expensive operation. It creates new internal array and copies all items from original array starting from index 1. Just use Queue - its a FIFO collection

Comment: I am trying to avoid it.  Which is why I am asking.  I just wrote the Queue code, and it is a lot neater than I thought it would be. I will post above

Comment: _And I want to iterate through it over and over, such as 0123012301230123...- Foreach is not what I am looking for, because I do not want everything all at once._ Now what on earth do you mean by that??? `Foreach`  is the standard Iterator; why exactly do you think you can't use it???

Comment: Meaning nextElementIsNeeded will usually be false, and will sometimes (unknown when) be true within my Game Loop.  Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy so that second block of code I wrote is the right approach?

Comment: Instead of constantly messing with the Container, why not use an index into the List?

Comment: Having 2 class members needed for the same thing is not something I am very comfortable with, unless it is something that I should be comfortable with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of constantly adding and removing the same Items to/from a collection (no matter which type), simply use a circular index to access the list you have.

```
int currentElementIndex = 0;
//..

if (nextElementIsNeeded)
{ 
  currentElementIndex = (currentElementIndex + 1) % foo.Count;
  thing = foo[currentElementIndex]; 
}
```

Comment: I was hesitant to use an extra field, but given my needs, a Queue gives me hiccups later, and cant really see a version of my problem where a Queue wouldnt give me hiccups later.  thanks for your answer! I ended up using it.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure of the practicality, but here's an extension method that would do it:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SelectForever<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    while(true)
        foreach(T item in source)
            yield return item;
}
```

or to add a projection:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectForever<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector)
{
    while(true)
        foreach(TSource item in source)
            yield return selector(item);
}
```

usage would be:

```
foreach(Thing item in foo.SelectForever())
{
    ...hopefully break at some point
}
```

or

```
foreach(string s in foo.SelectForever(item => item.ToString()))
{
    ...hopefully break at some point
}
```

Note that this is *only* possible because of deferred execution - calling `foo.SelectForever().ToList()` would run until it ran out of memory.

Comment: Well there goes my afternoon researching how all that works :) cool answer